Marginalizing out the unknown in probability density
This is a common identity in Bayesian ML, but I've always had a confusion about it. Suppose that $\mathcal{D}$ is the training data set, $w$ are some parameters. Our goal is to predict output $t$, given input $x$. Then, we have the following:

$$p(t|x,\mathcal{D}) = \int p(t|x,w)p(w|\mathcal{D}) \ \mathrm{d}w.$$

My question is: why does this hold? Would anybody have a proof? For example, my confusion is:
$$ \int p(t|x,w)p(w|\mathcal{D}) \ \mathrm{d}w = \int \frac{p(t,x,w)}{p(x,w)}\cdot \frac{p(w,\mathcal{D})}{p(\mathcal{D})} \ \mathrm{d}w = \frac{p(t,x,\mathcal{D})}{p(x,\mathcal{D})}???$$
It occurs to me that I might be interpreting things incorrectly or confusing myself, and in that case, I'd appreciate any clarifications.
There is a similar question in: "Marginalizing out" a parameter in a PDF, however I think this case is more straightforward and does not answer the question above:
$$ p(t) = \int p(t|x)p(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \int p(t,x) \ \mathrm{d}x.$$

Presumably $w$ is independent of new inputs $x$ once you condition on the data? Otherwise this probably does not hold in general. This is usually the case when $w$ is some parameters that characterize some regression model, but not the case when $w$ are, for example, latent parameters that underlie the distribution of $x$.

@daisies, yes, $w$ should be independent of $x$ once we condition on $\mathcal{D}$. In that case, would there be a good proof that the above property holds or is valid?

Then it's the same as the bottom line you wrote. The product inside the integral is the joint density of $t, w$, conditional on $x, \mathcal D$.

@daisies Sorry, I still don't think I understand. Would you mind writing things out for me a bit more? (Or in an answer format, and I will upvote)

From the comments, in your setup we have $$p(w \mid \mathcal D) = p(w \mid x, \mathcal D) ,$$ since $w$ is independent of $x$, conditional on the data. Very analogously, we (generally) have that the new regression problem should be independent of the training data (conditional on the trained parameters), and so $$p(t \mid x, w) = p(t \mid x, w, \mathcal D).$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int p(t \mid x, w)p(w \mid \mathcal D) dw &= \int p(t \mid w, x, \mathcal D)p(w \mid x, \mathcal D) dw \\ &= \int p(t, w \mid x, \mathcal D)dw \\ &= p(t \mid x, \mathcal D).
\end{align*}
First equality follows from above remarks; second by basic properties of the conditional density; third by definition of the joint.

Thank you for the clear answer!
